# include_vars: load multiple files under one variable name

Tags: ansible

I have situation with dependency between var files.
File A depends on var definitions in file B.
I'd like to load them under one variable name 'some variable', so I can use file A without 'undefined variable' errors.
files are not in the same directory, and I cant use recursive dir: to load everything this will cause variable overwrites.

loading like this won't work:

```
   include_vars:
     file: dirB/fileB
     file: dirA/fileA
     name: SomeVar
```

I tried to use set_fact and then 'combine' the two (giving them different var names), but that already causes undefined variable error in fileA

I've not defined directory structure it has a good purpose, my purpose is a little different than 'global' design.
Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

[vars_files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html) does what you want. For example, given the files

```yaml
shell> cat dirA/fileA.yml 
SomeVar: "{{ OtherVar }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat dirB/fileB.yml 
OtherVar: value of other var
```

The below play

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars_files:
    - dirA/fileA.yml
    - dirB/fileB.yml

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: SomeVar
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  SomeVar: value of other var
```